# Ubuntu C code how to execute command in another folder

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu, exec, popen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *buffer = malloc(1024);
    FILE* f = popen("ls", "r");
    int byteReads = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, f);
    fclose(f);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Ther are 2 folders `./parent/folder1` and `./parent/folder2` . `./main` is in folder1, and I want it to execute `ls` in folder2 and get the result.

Not something that is specific to "ls", but that works for any commands in general.

How can I do it using `popen()`? Or do I have to use another command?

Comment: take a look at [chdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html)

Comment: That's too specific. I don't want to do only "ls", but any commands in general

Comment: You should be using `opendir()`/`readdir()` or a higher level interface instead of trying to call `ls` from a C program.

Comment: In Linux and Unix and BSD, these are called "directories", not folders which is a Windows-ism and not the same thing.

Comment: Since you are already using `popen`, that open a shell, you could use `popen("cd parent/folder2 && ls", "r")`. This way your main program is not constantly changing its execution directory, that could be problematic (for example if you want multiple threads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use popen as you use it in your question. You could pass the cmd you want to execute as argument to the program call, e.g. if your program is named `myexecute` the command line call would look like this:

```
myexecute folder2 'ls -l'
```

or

```
myexecute 'another folder' 'ls'
```

Please note the single quotes to get an argument if spaces are included in the argument.

With `chdir` you can change the current working directory. The output of the command can be read in a loop and output to the stdout.
Finally, with pclose, you would wait for the associated process to finish and it would even return the exit status of the executed command, just in case you are interested.

You code slightly modified could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s '<dir>' '<cmd>'\n", basename(argv[0]));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(chdir(argv[1]) != 0) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE *f = popen(argv[2], "r");
    if (!f) {
        perror("popen failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char buf[1024];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    if (pclose(f) != 0) {
        perror("pclose failed");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: calling 'ls -l folder2'' isn't quite the same as 'execute ls in folder2' esp. when OP says "Not something that is specific to "ls"